# TSQL Where Statement OR + AND

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a very basic `SELECT` statement that is causing me some grief.

I have a primary table of tools that I am selecting data from. In that table, I only want tools where the `status` is not `Decommissioned`.

From there, I am checking the tool name against my `LIKE` clause to see if it's a close match. This is done for my AJAX typeahead.

Lastly, it's joining a table called `akas` which contains tool names that can also be used in reference to the main tool. These are basically other aliases the tools go by.

The issue I am facing is that it is still including records with the `Decommissioned` status. I am pretty sure its the `WHERE` clause.. Any thoughts?

```
   SELECT   t.toolName,
             t.tool AS toolID,
             t.toolType,
             t.toolStatus,
             e1.PreferredName AS ownerFirst,
             e1.LastName AS ownerLast,
             e1.NTID AS ownerNTID
    FROM     dbo.ti_tools AS t
             LEFT OUTER JOIN
             dbo.ti_toolAKAs AS a
             ON t.tool = a.tool
             LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.EmployeeTable AS e1
             ON t.toolOwner = e1.QID
    WHERE    (t.toolName LIKE '%' + @tool + '%') OR (a.aka LIKE '%' + @tool + '%')
             AND t.toolStatus <> 'Decommissioned'
    ORDER BY t.toolName ASC
    FOR      XML PATH ('tools'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Order of operations**

`AND` has *greater* precedence than `OR`.

Change your `WHERE` clause to the following, using parentheses around the two `OR` conditions to separate them logically from the commission check:

```
WHERE ((t.toolName LIKE '%' + @tool + '%') OR (a.aka LIKE '%' + @tool + '%'))
         AND t.toolStatus <> 'Decommissioned'
```

Your original `WHERE` clause was being evaluated identically to this:

```
WHERE (t.toolName LIKE '%' + @tool + '%') OR
      ((a.aka LIKE '%' + @tool + '%') AND t.toolStatus <> 'Decommissioned')
```

Answer (score 1):

Add round brackets:

```
SELECT   t.toolName,
             t.tool AS toolID,
             t.toolType,
             t.toolStatus,
             e1.PreferredName AS ownerFirst,
             e1.LastName AS ownerLast,
             e1.NTID AS ownerNTID
FROM dbo.ti_tools AS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ti_toolAKAs AS a
  ON t.tool = a.tool
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.EmployeeTable AS e1
  ON t.toolOwner = e1.QID
WHERE ((t.toolName LIKE '%' + @tool + '%') OR (a.aka LIKE '%' + @tool + '%'))
  AND t.toolStatus <> 'Decommissioned'
ORDER BY t.toolName ASC
FOR XML PATH ('tools'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

The case is very simple:

```
cond1 OR cond2 AND cond3
<=>
cond1 OR (cond2 AND cond3)
```

And you get records that satisfy only `cond1`. What you really want is:

```
(cond1 OR cond2) AND cond3
```